# Can I put a link to my blog for a longer answer?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, etiquette

So, recent creative questions and answers have triggered a crazy idea in my mind:

making a blog about some Worldbuilding questions and posts that interest me - and maybe posting some short stories, or writing longer answers there.

Of course, I want to put the link on the referenced question/answer (maybe as a comment, maybe in the post).

But I'm not sure if this is allowed, as this sounds like I'm promoting my blog. The blog will only (at least in my current plan) contains posts from Worldbuilding.SE, and I'm not sure about the frequency of the posts and posting links as comments/posts.

The links will be posted as comment, or included in posts ("If you are interested, here is a more in-depth explanation/a short story about what happened").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ok to link to your blog if you disclose the affiliation ("I wrote more about this on {my blog}" is fine for that), and so long as the post *here* is complete enough for the purposes of this site.  People shouldn't *have* to visit an external link in order to get a complete answer, but links to additional information are welcome.

This community is (so far as I've seen) interested in seeing the results of worldbuilding too, like fiction.  A link at the end of a relevant post or in a comment seems unobjectionable to me.  I did this in [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/71/28) and nobody complained.  Don't be spammy, like linking to your blog in unrelated posts, and if you find yourself doing it in many posts you might want to reconsider.

By the way, did you know that we have a [community blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory)?  You're welcome to submit your posts there too; here are the [submission guidelines](https://medium.com/universe-factory/want-to-contribute-b37191c4362e).  As you'll see if you browse the blog, we have a mix of fiction, science, worldbuilding how-to, and more.

Comment: Thanks! I've already known Universe Factory since about a month (?) ago, but I don't think my work will be too good enough for it - most of the times my brain only pop half of an idea and not good enough to put it beyond messy words ;) . I'm planning to get some kind of personal notes (online, so I can edit it anywhere) about these incomplete stuff (using interesting and correct vocabulary is a challenge to me).

Comment: @Vylix understood, and I'm not trying to discourage you from using your own blog (I have one too, after all :-) ).  Just wanted to make sure you know you have the option; if you have something that you think is polished enough, please feel free to submit it!